# No isnew function in formula field, how to work around?

Tags: formula-field

I need to check if a document is new (ISNEW()) in a formula field.

This is the formula if( YEAR( TODAY())= VALUE(Year__c),"True","False")

The issue is that I do not see ISNEW() as an option. How to get the formula to detect if the document is new? Do I need to do a WF and field update to another field and include it in the formula or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ISNEW in a formula field, as those are calculated on the fly, but you can use it directly in your WF criteria, such as:

```
OR(ISNEW(), Year(Today()) = Value(Year__c))
```

Functions like ISNEW and PRIORVALUE only work in workflow formula and validation rule criteria, since they do not make sense in the normal context of formula fields.

Be sure to check [the manual](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US) to determine which functions can be used when; each function will describe appropriate places it can be used.